# Installing Kubuntu 16.10 partitioning

Tags: system-installation

I am stuck at a installation type screen. I let kubuntu do it's automatic partition resize and I've been waiting 2 days for it it finish. It's only 338gb. On an hhd. Weird..

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, install has failed. It will finish in <10 min if it is going to work. Possible drive failure, possible your installer lacks device driver. It used to happen on some SSD. Possible also your install media corrupted.

Reboot and try again. Alt-Ctl-Delete or power button.

If same happens again, try again with settings you control. I would do custom partitions and choose old safe file system like ext4, not new fancy ones. I would avoid any new style volume manager.

If that fails, download standard ubuntu. If that works, KDE desktop can be added later.